# TCPDF - ÆØÅ from language file doesnt work

Tags: php, html, utf-8, tcpdf, html2pdf

I have a tcpdf template that I want to show norwegian letters like ÆØÅ
The font I am using is freesans.

The template gets dynamic information from the database and show ÆØÅ correcly but from the php language file it only show ? where theese letters should show.

Both template, connection to db and language file is coded with utf-8.

Any suggestion what could be wrong since the font I use does support this.

Comment: I can suggest looking at mpdf: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php  - In all my cases, it delivered better results than tcpdf, and it surely can handle a bigger amount of css rules :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this blogpost](http://mathijskadijk.nl/post/24012364005/custom-font-and-special-characters-in-tcpdf) that explains how to use custom fonts and characters in TCPDF. It points to [this font convert website](http://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf) that will help you to convert your fonts in a correct way so they will display special characters correctly.